# ECMAScript use cases?

Tags: javascript, windows

I have just a view questions:

Why should somebody write anything in plain ECMAScript (not JavaScript)? I cannot find anything about IO- or Socket-implementations of ECMAScript. Can I access a database or files on my filesystem? Am I able to perform batch processing? Can I run ECMAScript files in Windows?

Comment: depends what the job is - eg. if you are writing javascript on nodejs you are working to an `ECMA` edition standard, If you are doing actionscript you are working with another.

Comment: ECMAScript is _never_ used by itself -- it's meant to be supplemented by a host environment, such as what JavaScript (and the DOM) does.